# Get and Post code work properly but Put and Delete don't work

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi

I relatively new in pycharm and fastAPI and now for a couple of days i'm trying to figure how to send PUT and DELETE requests through fast API forms. I am trying to do curl POST, GET, PUT and DELETE using pycharm. Get and Post code work properly but Put and Delete don't work.

---

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

Student = {
    'student_1': {'full_name': 'Sarita Banjara', 'address': 'panauti', 'dob': 'dec 13 2001', 'citizenship': 12456},
    'student_2': {'full_name': 'Sajana Gurung', 'address': 'pokhara', 'dob': 'jun 07 2001', 'citizenship': 13457},
    'student_3': {'full_name': 'Mahendra Wagle', 'address': 'banepa', 'dob': 'aug 25 2001', 'citizenship': 14258},
    'student_4': {'full_name': 'Bishal Jung', 'address': 'santinagar', 'dob': 'nov 20 2001', 'citizenship': 15987},
    'student_5': {'full_name': 'Aayush Maskey', 'address': 'gaushala', 'dob': 'dec 23 1990', 'citizenship': 24356},
}
@app.get("/")
async def read_all_student():
    return Student


@app.post("/")
async def create_new_entry(student_full_name, student_address, student_dob, student_citizenship ):
     return Student

@app.put("/{student_name}")
async def update_student(student_full_name: str, student_address: str, student_dob: str, student_citizenship: str):
    student_information = {'Full Name': student_full_name, 'Address': student_address, 'DOB': student_dob, 'Citizenship': student_citizenship}
    Student[student_name] = student_information
    return student_information
@app.delete("/{full_name")
async def delete_student():
    return Student
white_check_mark
eyes
raised_hands
React
Reply

New

Sareeta Banzara  3:54 PM
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

Student = {
    'student_1': {'full_name': 'Sarita Banjara', 'address': 'panauti', 'dob': 'dec 13 2001', 'citizenship': 12456},
    'student_2': {'full_name': 'Sajana Gurung', 'address': 'pokhara', 'dob': 'jun 07 2001', 'citizenship': 13457},
    'student_3': {'full_name': 'Mahendra Wagle', 'address': 'banepa', 'dob': 'aug 25 2001', 'citizenship': 14258},
    'student_4': {'full_name': 'Bishal Jung', 'address': 'santinagar', 'dob': 'nov 20 2001', 'citizenship': 15987},
    'student_5': {'full_name': 'Aayush Maskey', 'address': 'gaushala', 'dob': 'dec 23 1990', 'citizenship': 24356},
}
@app.get("/")
async def read_all_student():
    return Student

@app.post("/")
async def create_new_entry(student_full_name, student_address, student_dob, student_citizenship):
    current_student_name = 0
    if len(Student) > 0:
        for student in Student:
            x = int(student.split('_')[-1])
            if x > current_student_name:
                current_student_name = x

    Student[f'student_{current_student_name + 1}'] = {'Full Name': student_full_name, 'Address': student_address, 'DOB': student_dob, 'Citizenship': student_citizenship }
    return Student[f'student_{current_student_name+ 1}']

@app.put("/full_name")
async def update_student(full_name: 'citizenship'):
    counter = 0

    for x in Student:
        counter += 1
        if x.citizenship == full_name:
            Student[counter -1] = Student
            return Student[counter -1]

@app.delete("/{student_full_name")
async def delete_student():
    return Student******
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare what you put in the placeholders for the endpoint name.

Try:

```
@app.put("/{student_name}")
async def update_student(student_name: str, ...):
    ...
@app.delete("/{full_name}")
async def delete_student(full_name: str, ...):
    ...
```

By the way, how are you requesting the endpoints ?

Comment: don't forget the missing curly bracket at delete

Answer (score 1):

The PUT endpoint is missing the key that you use to identify the student, see below code for the correct way:

```
@app.put("/student/{student_name}")
async def update_student(student_name: str, student_full_name: str, student_address: str, student_dob: str, student_citizenship: str):
    student_information = {'Full Name': student_full_name, 'Address': student_address, 'DOB': student_dob, 'Citizenship': student_citizenship}
    Student[student_name] = student_information
    return student_information
```

And in the DELETE endpoint you did not specify the key in the function, so it was not visible (and you were missing a closing curly bracket ). See update:

```
@app.delete("/student/{full_name}")
async def delete_student(full_name:str):
    return Student
```

I only looked at the top code, the rest of you provided code seems a duplicate??